# Compare two means with confidence intervals vs ttest

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test

I have two samples and I want to know how significant is the difference between their means. So I make the hypothesis that they both come from the same population.

What I did is to compute the parameters from my population using sample A. Hence the population is a Normal(mean(A), std(A)) distribution.

Numerically, I get approximately mean(A)=10.42, std(A)=1.07 hence 95% confidence interval of [8.33, 12.15].

I computed that mean(B)=10.51 which is in the interval. I even computed the area above mean(B) under my population curve Normal(mean(A), std(A)) and got that 46.6% of the area under the curve is above 10.51. I deduced that the p-value is 2*46.6% = 93.2% which is how likely it is to get a mean >= 10.51.

The 95% CI of B is (8.10, 12.93). For background, A and B are alcohol level measures in red and white wines and I want to discuss whether there is a difference between red and white wines alcohol measures.

I am not sure about the validity of my approach. Also, if I apply a 1 sample t-test with population mean=mean(A) and sample=B, I get a p-value < 0.1% and I cannot explain why there is such a difference. And a 2 sample ttest gives a 0.4% p-value.

How to explain such a difference?

Comment: What is the 95%CI of B?

Comment: Also, the so called "population curve" is not the right reference. Mean(A) is correct, but the dispersion is standard error of A and not the SD. In addition, both paired and independent t-tests considered the variance within B. but your first approach if one-sample t-test does not.

Comment: As well as @Penguin_Knight comments one could point out that in a nutshell your approaches are assuming you know for sure something(s) which in fact you are only estimating.

Comment: The 95% CI of B is (8.10, 12.93). For background, A and B are alcohol level measures in respectively red and white wines and I want to discuss whether there is a difference between red and white wines alcohol measures.

Comment: Hi again. The CI formula has problem. Looking at A. The CI should be 10.42+/- 1.96*SE. Where SE = SD/sqrt(group n). It seems you just used SD in place of SE.

Comment: Better in any event to calculate the difference between the means and have a confidence interval for that. If you just want to know if there is a difference why not use your two sample t-test?

Comment: Thanks both. I used SD in place of SE. the CI is now (10.480, 10.549). Yes I should use two sample t-test.

Comment: For this particular problem, I think that a 2-sample T test would be more appropriate， since the hypotesis is mainly on the significance level of the difference of two groups. However, you calculated the confidence interval *only* on sampleA, so you ignored the variance of sampleB, which may bias your conclusion.